# Target class does not exist - Route:List - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working in Laravel project and when I'm trying to see the my routes list this error appear.

`Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist.`

But, in fact, this controller exists, since I'm using the Laravel authentication method and in my `web.php` I'm calling `Auth::routes().`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload` if you have created the file manually. Also check the file has the appropriate namespace

Comment: Thank you for you comment, but none of the possibilities work. I didn't create the file manually, and the namespace is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your auth controller in a custom directory then you can't use auth routes. As akbar has already pointed out, you need to remove `Auth::routes()` and define the routes yourself.

e.g.

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

It's either that or to put your LoginController back in the Controllers directory

Comment: Thanks you! That actually works. I did something wrong with akbar answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try these solutions:

1.Define routes `maually` and remove `Auth::routes()`

2.If your laravel version is lower that 5.2 use `Route::auth()`instead of `Auth::routes()`

Comment: I will try the first one, since I'm using a higher version than 5.2. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I remove the Auth::routes() and define my routes manually, but now, I can't login anymore. I defined the same controller LoginController and the same function showLoginForm. Any idea? Btw, the problem persists. I still can't see my route list.